# md5sum of apk changes after every build

Tags: android, md5sum

Why does the `md5sum` value of an `apk` change after every build?

Every time i build my Android application in the Eclipse IDE using the `Android Tools -> Export Signed Application package`, i get an `apk` file that gives a different `md5sum` value. If i have not changed any of the source code, shouldn't the `apk` files give the exact same `md5sum`? This happens even if i build it just seconds apart. What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The individual files should compile with the same CRC. An APK however is like a zip file containing all your files and those files are stored with a timestamp. The timestamp will be different for each compile and this is what changes your md5sum.

Comment: the timestamp should be the same for every file in the project since i did not make any changes. You mean there is one separate apk wide timestamp that changes for every compile right?